# How to do a Hockney style with Blender?

Tags: image, effects

How can I do a Hockney style with Blender like ones in the video below ?

[example on youtube](https://youtu.be/INRVtPILIDQ?t=26)

This is an example of the Hockney Style I'm looking to create:

[image: desired result]

Comment: What is a "hockney style"? Please edit your question and explain with your own words or post reference images what you are trying to achieve, don't rely on videos for users to figure out what you want to do

Comment: I have added an example ;)

Comment: Hockney's woks are about describing a place from multiple perspectives simultaneously. What you need is multiple images of the same place from different points of view, map those on to planes and arrange at will. Otherwise you are just tiling the same image.

Answer (score 5):

## Summary

This is easily done with the camera or window texture coordinate in cycles, but you could also easily do it with uv project instead.

#### Final result:

[image]

---

## 1. Modeling

Modeling this is obviously very straightforward. Add a plane, then go into edit mode and add a bunch more! Vary the heights of the planes so that they occlude each other, and spread them out in a visually pleasing manner. This shouldn't take more than 2-3 minutes to finish.

In the GIF, after I finish this modeling (which I skipped most of to save time), I unwrap it using "project from view" while in an overhead view. Depending on the image you are projecting onto, you may need to scale it to make it more square in the UV/Image Editor.

[image]

## 2. Material Setup

The material setup is likewise simple. Add an image texture node that uses a UV map node to provide the color input of a diffuse shader.

```
UVMap --> Image Texture --> Diffuse --> Material Output
```

[image]

## 3. Lighting

### a. Setup sun lamp

Add a sun lamp and rotate it to get the nice shadows you would expect. In the GIF, I also change the world color to something close to white for increased ambient light (this is more personal preference).

[image]

### b. Setup backdrop for those shadows

Add a plane behind the model that can receive the shadows from the planes that are in the model.

[image]